# "Yesterday you didn't tell me John was with Finch last year"

Tags: present-perfect

"*Yesterday* you *didn't* tell me John *was* with Finch last year" here why aren't we using "John had been with Finch last year"? (since I spoke to you yesterday and with respect to that shouldn't it be "had been with Finch").  In spoken English why do we often use this structure (i.e. simple past for past perfect?)

By 'was with Finch' I mean they worked together in an office .

Comment: Convenience, probably.

Comment: What do you mean by 'was with'? Do you mean 'was on Finch's side', 'agreed with Finch', 'was physically in Finch's presence', 'was residing with Finch'? As is so often the case with questions like this, context is key.

Comment: "was with" is pretty ambiguous. I think "had been" denotes a relationship ^_^

Comment: I agree with Zoe. Had been makes it sound like they were in a relationship last year. Was can have more meanings to it.

Comment: Can anyone give a elaborative answer to my question. Comments aren't helpful.

Comment: Does your question imply that you think that prefacing the sentence with _Yesterday you didn't tell me_ should affect the tense used in the subordinate clause?

Answer (score 2):

I think *John was with Finch last year* vs *John had been with Finch last year* is a matter of where *John* is now.

*had been with Finch* suggests that *John* is no longer with *Finch* but *had been* there last year.

*was with Finch* doesn't suggest that *John* is no longer with *Finch* but it might have a hint of it.

*John has been with Finch since last year* definitely suggests he is still with *Finch*.

It's not an easy term to pin down an exact answer for though, much like *Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments* appears to be.